# Receiving an error when attempting to display a bar graph in jupyter note book

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner and need help discovering my mistake in this code. I am trying to display a bar graph but receive an error instead. my code before the `df.head()` statement is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("heart-disease.csv")
```

[image]

Comment: `value_counts()` instead of `value.counts()`

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo:

```
df.target.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```